# How do you find the item container given the object in a ContentControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

To specify my question more, let's say, I have a expander control and its content is a Grid.
I have a handle to the Grid only and I would like to get the parent control, which contains that Grid. If I try to get a parent, I will get real parent, but not a Control, which is a content of the Expander.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code [`VisualTreeHelper.GetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent.aspx):

```
DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(controlChild);
```

Comment: I 'am happy to help you wh1sp3r